# Algorithmic Complexity of Enqueue and Dequeue of a Special Queue

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, algorithms, queueing-theory

**The Canteen Queue Problem**: There is a common canteen for $K$ hostels. Each hostel (co-ed) has some $N_1, N_2,...,N_K$ students. These students line up to pick up their trays in the common canteen, in a queue.
The queue is implemented as follows: If a student sees a person from his/her hostel, she/he joins the queue behind this person. This is the “enqueue” operation. The “dequeue” operation is as usual, at the front. How would we implement such a queue? Additionally, what would be the time complexity of the enqueue and dequeue operations? Would the average waiting time in this queue would be higher or lower than a normal queue?

**Edit** : Each student arrives uniformly in a given time period $T$

Comment: What is the law for arrivals ? each student arrives uniformly in a given time period ? Following a gaussian around a time reference ? something else ? For the implementation, this is more a stackoverflow question, but you can just have a linked list, and you keep a pointer for each hostel to the last student of the hostel in the queue, every operation would be constant time.

Comment: Yes, uniform arrival in a given time period (T)

Comment: Do you want to calculate it with a service time, or assume that nobody is served and calculate the average number of people that ends in front of you at the end of the process (ok, first case probably, the second is almost trivial, the students will end up stacked by hostel, sorted by the arrival of the first student of each hostel)?

Comment: I think the average waiting time should not change as the cumulative waiting time of every student should be the same than for a normal queue. What would be interesting to study is the variance of the waiting time.